# bytearray to string python2 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to get bytearray as string on python3.
on python 2.7 , str(bytearray) results the contents of bytearray in string format.

```
    Python 2.7.18 (default, Feb  8 2022, 09:11:29)
    [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> c = bytearray(b'\x80\x04\x95h\x00\x00')
    >>> str(c)
    '\x80\x04\x95h\x00\x00'
    >>>
```

on python 3.6, even the "bytearray" keyword is added into the resulting string.

```
    Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 12 2021, 07:06:15)
    [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> c = bytearray(b'\x80\x04\x95h\x00\x00')
    >>> str(c)
    "bytearray(b'\\x80\\x04\\x95h\\x00\\x00')"
    >>>
```

1. why is it happening so on 3.6 ?
2. how to get the exact same behavior on 3.6 as that of 2.7 ?
   Note: I cannot do c.decode(), as those are compressed/pickled data which will result in invalid start byte errors.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: "I cannot do c.decode()" but that's how you convert a bytearray to a string.

Comment: Of cause you can use `decode()`. You just have to give the right encoding as argument.

Comment: And also if you want to get the same result as in Python 2, you just don't do anything, as `c` already is a bytearray (which was identical to a string in Python 2). Maybe you want `bytes(c)`?

Comment: >>> bytes(c)
'\x80\x04\x95h\x00\x00'
>>>

on 3.6, 
>>> bytes(c)
b'\x80\x04\x95h\x00\x00'

Comment: String means text. You don't have text, you have pickle data, which is just bytes. It makes no sense to convert this to string. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: One of the most far-reaching changes (and by far the hardest to migrate) in Python 3 was to distinguish between a string (`str`, text, capable of representing any Unicode character natively) and a bunch of bytes (`bytes` or `bytearray`). In Python 2 that was dependent on the programmer's intent and not on the datatype. You can get *equivalent* behaviour in Python 2 and Python 3. But you can't get the *same* behaviour. That is by design.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i am trying to migrate an old code base into py3. because it was on py2.x , in one condition the code returns string , and in other condition its bytes. it worked in py2 as BoarGules suggested above. I would need some fixing here.

Comment: "in one condition the code returns string , and in other condition its bytes" What does this mean in python 2 data types? string = `unicode` and bytes = `str`?

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method for the `bytearray` class is different in Python 3, to obtain a similar result you could try below snippet.

```
>>> str(bytes(c))
"b'\\x80\\x04\\x95h\\x00\\x00'"
```